# how to direct the out put of a SQL query to pane instead of a text file

Tags: sql

What is the setting for out putting the query result to pane, instead of text file. I set output to text file a long time ago. But I forgot how to turn it back. Please advise.

Thanksa

Comment: It would be helpful if you described what you're remotely talking about.

Comment: Are you using SQL Server management Studio or what?

Comment: In a query window, Right click, open the Results To menu, and select results to grid

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure any further comment is needed.
[image: DerpDerp]

If you are not using SSMS then push your particular data management tool's equivalent button.